# How do I reverse the order of an array using v-for and orderBy filter in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am using Vue JS to do viewmodel bindings. In my `data` object I have an array of items that are sorted in ascending order (oldest to newest) and I'd like to keep it that way for code-based reasons.

```
var v = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        items: [
            {id: 51,  message: 'first'},
            {id: 265, message: 'second'},
            {id: 32,  message: 'third'}
        ],
    }
}
```

However, when I display the array in the template I'd like to reverse the order so that it's descending (newest to oldest). I tried the following:

```
<ol>
    <li v-for="item in items | orderBy -1" track-by="id">
```

This didn't work since the `orderBy` filter seems to require a field name as its first argument.

Is there any way to accomplish this in the template using the `v-for` syntax using the `orderBy` filter? Or am I going to have to create a custom `reverse` filter?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> **Note:** The below works in Vue 1, but in Vue 2 filters are deprecated and you
>   will see: ' Property or method "reverse" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render.'  See *tdom_93's* answer for
>   vue2.

You could create a custom filter to return the items in reversed order:

```
Vue.filter('reverse', function(value) {
  // slice to make a copy of array, then reverse the copy
  return value.slice().reverse();
});
```

Then use it in the `v-for` expression:

```
<ol>
    <li v-for="item in items | reverse" track-by="id">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pespantelis/sgsdm6qc/

Comment: Not worked in vue 2.0,error is ' Property or method "reverse" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.'

Answer (score 170):

Simple and concise solution:

```
<li v-for="item in items.slice().reverse()">
//do something with item ...
</li>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Why do people make things so complicated? Rhetorical.

Comment: Although this is one solution to the answer, i'd say you have to look from the eyes of the developer giving the solution. A lot of seasoned developers strive to keep business logic and display logic separate. Especially those whom have dealt with the pain points of merging the two together. This solution works and yes it is a great alternative or additional solution. However it does mix business logic with display logic a little further than most would consider acceptable.

Comment: @RyanWatts that is why the `.slice()` method is used. It will return a new array, so the original `items` array will not be affected.

Comment: It works but returns me an error in my console *slice is not a function*

Comment: Isn't this, like, awfully inefficient? You create a copy of the array instead of just iterating over it from the last index rather than first...

Comment: @klesun - I think the particular problem here is you can't control the iteration of the v-for directive directly.  You would have to create a new view directive, and for such a simple problem that's an absurd amount of work IMAO.

Comment: @tempra: I know, this is late, but I had the same issue. For me the problem was, that I initialized "items" as an object instead of an array in the data object of Vue (although loading in a pure array into the property later). So "items: []" instead of "items: {}" at initalization did it for me.

Answer (score 48):

Instead of reversing the order of the elements for creation, I only change the order of the display.

```
<ol class="reverseorder">
    <li v-for="item in items" track-by="id">
```

And my CSS

```
<style>
.reverseorder {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
</style>
```

No need to clone the array and reverse it.

Comment: This is the ideal answer as of now.. Doing a reverse in Javascript array is another processing

Comment: Wow! This is the brilliant solution. Lightweight and very flexible) Thanks

Comment: As a sidenote, this does not reverse the tab indices - meaning the tabbing order will be wrong. This isn't great for accessibility, so keep that in mind if you are working with interactive elements (like inputs, for example).

Comment: What the awesome solution I like, thank a lot.

Answer (score 32):

## Update for Vue2

I want to show some ways that you can work with data and not using filters as they are **deprecated** in Vue2:

**inside computed property**

Use computed properties in place of filters, which is much better because you can use that data everywhere in component, not only just in template:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9woazy4/2/)

```
computed: {
    reverseItems() {
        return this.items.slice().reverse();
  }     
}
```

**inside Vuex getter property**

If you're using Vuex, and you store your data in `store.state` object. The best way do some transformation with data stored in state is to do that in `getters` object (*for example filtering through a list of items and counting them, reverse order and so on...*)

```
getters: {
    reverseItems: state => {
        return state.items.slice().reverse();
    }
}
```

and retrieve state from getters in component computed property:

```
computed: {
    showDialogCancelMatch() {
        return this.$store.state.reverseItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a mistake, the second snippet should read: `return store.getters.reverseItems`

Comment: This creates a computed array which is fine and works but when you go to delete the items from the original data source the index keys are different. Any way to keep the keys the same so deleting is not an issue?

Comment: The computed works!!

Answer (score 2):

Possibly I'm missing some downsides here, but how about iterating over the array from end to start using *an index*?

```html
<ol>
  <li v-for="i in items.length" :set="item = items[items.length - i]">
```

Like, if your array consists of thousands of elements, copying it with `.slice().reverse()` every time is probably not the most efficient approach.

Upd.: note, `:set` is [not an official way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56249209/2750743) for defining variables in template, it just works. As an alternative, the `item` variable could be replaced by a call to some `getItem(i)` method that would encapsulate the `items[items.length - i]` expression.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with the latest vue, it iterates the correct number of times but item is the same object each time

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that the directive **`v-for` can accept not only an array but also any other valid JavaScript iterable object** (at least in Vue 2.6+ and Vue 3 releases), we can create our own iterable object to loop through a needed array in the opposite direction. I created a very simplified runnable example (for more details - check information about the [JavaScript iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)).

```js
class Iterable {
  constructor(arr) {
    this.arr = arr;
  }

  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    const arr = this.arr;
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) yield arr[i];
  }

  getIterable(isReversedOrder) {
    return isReversedOrder ? this : this.arr;
  }
}

Vue.component('list', {
  props: ['iterable'],
  template: '<ul><li v-for="(el, i) in iterable" :key="`${i}-${el}`">{{ el }}</li></ul>'
});

const app = new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      todos: new Iterable(['Learn JavaScript', 'Learn Vue', 'Learn Vuex']),
      isReversed: true,
      inputValue: ''
    };
  },

  computed: {
    computedTodos() {
      return this.todos.getIterable(this.isReversed);
    }
  },

  methods: {
    toggleReverse() {
      this.isReversed = !this.isReversed;
    },

    addTodo() {
      this.inputValue && this.todos.arr.push(this.inputValue);
      this.inputValue = '';
    }
  }
});

app.$mount('#app');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <div id="app">
        <button @click="toggleReverse">Toggle reverse to {{ !isReversed }}</button>
        <br />
        <input v-model="inputValue" style="margin-top:5px;" />
        <button @click="addTodo" :disabled="!inputValue">Add todo</button>
        <!-- <ul><li v-for="(todo, i) in computedTodos" :key="`${i}-${todo}`">{{ todo }}</li></ul> -->
        <list :iterable="computedTodos" />
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S.Try to avoid using such `Array.prototype` functions as `shift`/ `unshift` , `reverse` etc. to add / remove items from the beginning of the array or reverse the order, especially in the case when such operations are performed frequently and / or an array includes a big quantity of items, because they are quite costly as for performance (have O(n) complexity).
Another good solution is to use CSS to display elements in the reversed order (see an answer above).

Answer (score 0):

The v-for directive doesn't support iterating backwards, so if you want to order by newest you're going to need to add another field to indicate when the item was added, or change `id` to increment every time an item is added.

Then, with `field` being the field indicting the order added:

```html
<li v-for="item in items | orderBy 'field' -1" track-by="id">
```

Answer (score 0):

For my use case (which is admittedly, apparently different than the OP...) I wanted to have the indices of the Array **in reverse order** in the v-for "loop."

My solution was to create a Vue app method `reverseRange(length)` that returns an Array of integers from length-1 to 0. I then used that in my `v-for` directive and simply referred to my Array elements as `myArray[index]` every time I needed it.

That way, the indices were in reverse order and I was able to then use them to access elements of the Array.

I hope this helps someone who landed on this page with this subtle nuance in their requirements like me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lodash reverse](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#reverse):

```
<li v-for="item in _.reverse(items)">
```