# How to define a temporary variable in Vue.js template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Here is my current template:

```
<a-droppable v-for="n in curSize" :key="n - 1" :style="{width: `${99.99 / rowLenMap[orderList[n - 1]]}%`, order: orderList[n - 1]}">
  <a-draggable :class="{thin: rowLenMap[orderList[n - 1]] > 10}">
    <some-inner-element>{{rowLenMap[orderList[n - 1]]}}</some-inner-element>
  </a-draggable>
</a-droppable>
```

The problem is that i have to write `rowLenMap[orderList[n - 1]]` multiple times, and i'm afraid vue.js engine will also calculate it multiple times.

What i want is something like this:

```
<a-droppable v-for="n in curSize" :key="n - 1" v-define="rowLenMap[orderList[n - 1]] as rowLen" :style="{width: `${99.99 / rowLen}%`, order: orderList[n - 1]}">
  <a-draggable :class="{thin: rowLen > 10}">
    <some-inner-element>{{rowLen}}</some-inner-element>
  </a-draggable>
</a-droppable>
```

I think it's not difficult to implement technically because it can be clumsily solved by using something like `v-for="rowLen in [rowLenMap[orderList[n - 1]]]"`. So is there any concise and official solution?

Comment: Do a method. I think that's the cleanest way to go without changing your data structure. Accessing to two array elements by index shouldn't be noticeable even if it's computed each time anyway.

Comment: There is no vue directive to change data structure from template. As solution you can watch and regenerate curSize depending on orderList/rowLenMap. n will become object with three fields: n: your n, list amf len

Comment: I think a method is not brief enough in case 2 or 3 or more parameters is required. @Cobaltway

Comment: Similar to the accepted answer. Maybe a computed prop is little better than a watcher. Thx. @KirillMatrosov

Comment: https://github.com/posva/vue-local-scope

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`curSize` is an array. Your temporary values comprise a corresponding implied array `sizedOrderList = curSize.map(n => orderList[n-1])`. If you define that as a computed, your HTML becomes

```
<a-droppable v-for="n, index in sizedOrderList" :key="curSize[index]" :style="{width: `${99.99 / rowLenMap[n]}%`, order: n}">
  <a-draggable :class="{thin: rowLenMap[n] > 10}">
    <some-inner-element>{{rowLenMap[n]}}</some-inner-element>
  </a-draggable>
</a-droppable>
```

Comment: Create a computed to take place of the original list. A good solution for now.

Answer (score 188):

I found a very simple (almost magical) way to achieve that,
All it does is define an inline (local) variable with the value you want to use multiple times:

```html
<li v-for="id in users" :key="id" :set="user = getUser(id)">
  <img :src="user.avatar" />
  {{ user.name }}
  {{ user.homepage }}
</li>
```

Note : `set` is not a special prop in `Vuejs`, it's just used as a placeholder for our variable definition.

`Source`: https://dev.to/pbastowski/comment/7fc9

`CodePen`: https://codepen.io/mmghv/pen/dBqGjM

---

**Update : Based on comments from @*vir us***

This doesn't work with events, for example `@click="showUser(user)"` will not pass the correct user, rather it will always be the last evaluated user, that's because the `user` temp variable will get re-used and replaced on every circle of the loop.

So this solution is only perfect for template rendering because if component needs re-render, it will re-evaluate the variable again.

**But** if you really need to use it with events (although not advisable), you need to define an outer array to hold multiple variables at the same time :

```html
<ul :set="tmpUsers = []">
  <li v-for="(id, i) in users" :key="id" :set="tmpUsers[i] = getUser(id)" @click="showUser(tmpUsers[i])">
    <img :src="tmpUsers[i].avatar" />
    {{ tmpUsers[i].name }}
    {{ tmpUsers[i].homepage }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/mmghv/pen/zYvbPKv

credits : **@vir us**

Although it doesn't make sense here to basically duplicate the `users` array, this could be handy in other situations where you need to call expensive functions to get the data, but I would argue you're better off using `computed` property to build the array then.

Comment: This works, but it has a side effect of adding an attribute (`set="[object Object]"`) to the output, which is probably not wanted (although harmless).

Comment: Not working for me. Goes into infinite loop, Console error says You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

Comment: Vue 2.5.2 version

Comment: @sureshvv seems to be working just fine here https://codepen.io/mmghv/pen/qzMbVB
Please provide a pen that reproduce the error you mentioned.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be evaluated correctly if used inside @click for example. Seems like only the value evaluated for the first item of v-for is used inside all listeners. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: It shouldn't be used like that, it's nothing more than a temporary variable only meant to save you from repeating code or executing an expensive method multiple times when rendering, none of which is important when calling an event, as of why this is happening is because the variable is being overwritten on each cycle of the loop, for it to work it needs to keep track of each individual value and save it as a new variable in ram, which is not so efficient, after all you will find that most of the times it's actually better to be passing the identifier to the callback to access the source.

Comment: great, thanks for the clarification, that makes perfect sense! In this case one can "fix" it using an array defined outside of the loop. Here is a working example, I'll just leave it here as a demo for those who might be interested: https://codepen.io/username324/pen/JjjpgYr

Comment: ohh that's not good man, you're basically duplicating the users array here, adding a redundant data to memory. all you need to do is pass only the ID to the callback and let it call the function that gets the user data https://codepen.io/mmghv/pen/QWWQevj

Comment: yeah, I've got your point about passing id to make the calculation inside the callback - that's the approach I'm taking actually. I'm not quite sure though why in my example it's duplicating the array? It's defined once outside of the loop and then you only store and access data in it by index. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Users data are already defined in an array/object, which you're copying to a new array at render time, you're better off using the source data `usersData[id].xxx`, rule of thumb : only use this style of temporary variable for template rendering only.

Comment: oh, I see - you are talking about this particular example. Yes, it will copy the array since this is a very simple example. The idea was to demonstrate the approach of reusing "complex computation" though and this is how one can technically overcome a pitfall with listeners which might be handy. Of course you can pass the same function to perform the calculation one more time, which you've already mentioned. It's more a memory/time/readability tradeoff at this point. Not such a big deal, but just for the sake of completeness worth mentioning.

Comment: I've realized that by doing `tmpUsers[i] = tmpUsers[i] || getUser(id)` you can sort of keep the value between renders. Of course, you might encounter edge cases because of the boolean evaluation, but it does the job.

Comment: Using this method generates _[Vue warn]: Property or method "xxx" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties._

Any way to avoid this?

Comment: @dmikam this doesn't happen with me, you can check the codepen there's no warnings, can you provide a codepen that produces this warning?

Comment: @MohamedGharib Your codepen will generate the warning I mentioned if not minified vue library version used.

Comment: @dmikam you're right, I've been using this trick and never got a warning but I'm using vue CLI, it will give the warning only when you import vue directly in a script tag, not sure why is that.

Comment: It's great, but it should probably be `:data-set="..."` instead, otherwise it is not valid HTML.

Comment: how its do for vue 3 ?  ":set="user = getUser(id)""

Comment: using `set` may cause future compatibility issues.

Comment: I'm getting a Visual Studio complaint about "Property 'X' does not exist on type "... Is there any way to fix this issue or turn it off? The code itself seems fine...

Answer (score 15):

Today I needed this and used `<template>` tag and `v-for` like this
I took this code and

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="key in keys" 
      v-if="complexComputation(key) && complexComputation(key).isAuthorized">
    {{complexComputation(key).name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Changed it to this

```
<ul>
  <template v-for="key in keys">
    <li v-for="complexObject in [complexComputation(key)]"
        v-if="complexObject && complexObject.isAuthorized">
      {{complexObject.name}}
    </li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

And it worked and I was pleasantly surprised because I didn't know this was possible

Comment: nice trick!!! working fine, much thx. but one suggestion, please create a much simpler example when you provide an answer.

Comment: Very nice combined use of template tag and v-for="item in [singleton]". This solution has no unwanted side effect at all. If multiple shortcut variables are needed, we can further make the singleton an Object literal.

Comment: This is the best answer here.

Answer (score 13):

Judging by your template, you're probably best off with a computed property, as suggested in the accepted answer.

However, since the question title is a bit broader (and comes up pretty high on Google for "variables in Vue templates"), I'll try to provide a more generic answer.

---

Especially if you don't need every item of an array transformed, a computed property can be kind of a waste. A child component may also be overkill, in particular if it's really small (which would make it 20% template, 20% logic, and 60% props definition boilerplate).

A pretty straightforward approach I like to use is a small helper component (let's call it `<Pass>`):

```js
const Pass = {
  render() {
    return this.$scopedSlots.default(this.$attrs)
  }
}
```

Now we can write your component like this:

```js
<Pass v-for="n in curSize" :key="n - 1" :rowLen="rowLenMap[orderList[n - 1]]" v-slot="{ rowLen }">
  <a-droppable :style="{width: `${99.99 / rowLen}%`, order: orderList[n - 1]}">
    <a-draggable :class="{thin: rowLen > 10}">
      <some-inner-element>{{rowLen}}</some-inner-element>
    </a-draggable>
  </a-droppable>
</Pass>
```

`<Pass>` works by creating a scoped slot. Read more about scoped slots on the [Vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) or about the approach above in the [dev.to article](https://dev.to/loilo92/an-approach-to-vuejs-template-variables-5aik) I wrote on the topic.

---

## Appendix: Vue 3

Vue 3 has a slightly different approach to slots. First, the `<Pass>` component source code needs to be adjusted like this:

```js
const Pass = {
  render() {
    return this.$slots.default(this.$attrs)
  }
}
```

Comment: So this does not work with vue 3, I tried to migrate `return this.$slots.default(this.$attrs);`
but I get 
`Property "locale" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. at <Var locale="en" >`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @phper. I have added the Vue 3 compatible component definition using `$slots` and also adjusted the usage code (migrated from `slot-scope` to `v-slot`) so it's compatible with Vue 2.6+ and Vue 3. :)

Comment: If you need to keep typing information about fallthrough attributes when using typescript: https://github.com/posva/vue-local-scope/issues/17#issuecomment-1839385652

Answer (score 9):

Just tested using vue3 and works, i think it works universally

```
{{ (somevariable = 'asdf', null) }}
<span v-if="somevariable=='asdf'">Yey</span>
<span v-else>Ney</span>
```

It outputs nothing while setting your variable.

mandatory:

opening "("

set your variable

closing ", null)"

Comment: the same can also be achieved using the [void operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) `{{ void(somevariable = 'asdf') }}`

Comment: Note: the `, null` (or `void`) is necessary to prevent rendering the content (`"asdf"` in this example).

Comment: Also, to make Typescript not complain about this, I also had to define the type of my `someVariable` in my `<script>` somewhere.

Comment: best solution, imho

Answer (score 5):

This seems like the perfect use case of a child component. You can simply pass your complex computed value(s) as a property to the component.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props

Comment: I see this a lot for Vue and I don't like this argument that "everything should be a component".  I have plenty of "components" that are only used once.  Vue coders should be able to make an "inline component" so that they don't need to manage a whole new file.

Comment: So do it, you can create a component anywhere.... https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: Or just add additional code to the template in question. Many of my component are "born" this way. Where I extract the template code from a larger component to reuse through out the application.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
<div id="app">
  <div
    v-for="( id, index, user=getUser(id) ) in users"
    :key="id"
  >
    {{ user.name }}, {{ user.age }} years old
    <span @click="show(user)">| Click to Show {{user.name}} |</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/Vladimir-Miloevi/pen/xxJZKKx

Answer (score 3):

In some situations a `v-define` or `v-set` would indeed be helpful to prevent executing something repeatedly (although a computed property is sometimes better). You could use `v-for` with an array having just that value.

```
<template v-for="user in [getUser(id)]">
Hello {{ user.name }}!
</template>
```

would have the same effect as the hypothetical  `v-set`:

```
<template v-set="user=getUser(id)">
Hello {{ user.name }}!
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in itemsList" :key="item.id">
      {{ item.name }}

      <input v-model="item.description" type="text" />
      <button type="button" @click="exampleClick(item.id, item.description)">
        Click
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Name1',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Name2',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    itemsList() {
      return this.items.map((item) => {
        return Object.assign(item, { description: '' })
      })
    },
  },
  methods: {
    exampleClick(id, description) {
      alert(JSON.stringify({ id, description }))
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing an example from [Mohamed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56249209/1398417).
To get it working in Vue3 with TypeScript I used Array.prototype.map() to create new objects where I call the function.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    usersData: {
      1: {name: 'Mohamed', age: 29},
      2: {name: 'Ahmed', age: 27},
      3: {name: 'Zizo', age: 32},
      4: {name: 'John', age: 13},
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getUser(id) {
      return this.usersData[id];
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="{ id, user } in users.map((id) => ({ id: id, user: getUser(id) }))" :key="id">{{ user.name }}, {{ user.age }} years old</div>
</div>
```