# Any problems with defining variables inside v-for?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

AFAIK, first shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999618/how-to-define-a-temporary-variable-in-vue-js-template/74924843#74924843) by Vladimir Milosevic

```
 <div
    v-for="( id, index, user=usersData[id], doubleId=doubleThat(id) ) in users"
    :key="id"> 
    {{ user.name }}, {{ user.age }} years old And DoubleId = {{ doubleId }}
  </div>
```

I expanded his [codepen](https://codepen.io/iiydejib/pen/oNMdWPP?editors=1111). Looks like you can define several variables local to the loop this way.

Are there any side-effects or risks you see with this technique?
I find this way to be the most convenient and clean out there but since that is apparently not the intended use it may not be future-proof.

EDIT:

Here is another [pen](https://codepen.io/iiydejib/pen/oNMdJEY?editors=1011) which demonstrates the use case better. While here we reference just one computed property in one place, if the number of properties and references grows, it will lead to a verbose code.

Comment: Could probably destructure + rename on the fly tbh, will be cleaner and more readable IMO.

Comment: @kissu, if I understand you correctly, this would work in this simple example, however the challenge I face often is when for every cycle I need to access data in several nested structures. That leads to long expressions in the template as I am trying to traverse 1-3 levels of those jsons.

Comment: Still valid, even more in those cases tbh.

Comment: @kissu, I made a new pen to demonstrate what I mean, please see the edit. How would you go about simplifying that without defining variables in the template? Thanks for taking the time btw

Comment: This kind of problem is why Vue js has the computed properties. Calling functions inside a template is as a rule of thumb a bad idea, as vue needs to always rerender the component on each update. If you use computed properties vue can cache the computed values and only update if needed.

Comment: @LeifMarcus, see the pen I attached in the edit. I do use a computed property there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I think the clean way to do what you want to do is to bring the data into a format, where you can loop over it without extra steps. This way, you will never need those additional variables in `v-for`.

The example from your codepen could look like this:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    years: [2024, 2025, 2120],
    usersData: {...}
  },
  computed: {
    // user objects for each year
    ageData() {
      return Object.fromEntries(this.years.map(year => [year, 
        Object.values(this.usersData).map(user => this.userInYear(user, year))
      ] ))
    }
  },
  methods: {
    userInYear(user, year){
      return {...user, age: user.age + (year - 2023)}
    }
  },
});
```

Now you can iterate it without interruption and shenanigans:

```html
<div v-for="(users, year) in ageData" :key="year">
  <b>In {{ year }}:</b>
  <div v-for="user in users" :key="user.name"> 
    {{ user.name }} will be {{ user.age }} years old.
  </div>
</div>
```

It is easier to read and change, and it has the added benefit that you can inspect `ageData` in the console.

That said, I think it is very interesting that you can declare additional variables in `v-for`, I assume it is possible because of the way vue parses and builds expressions from the provided string, I am pretty sure it won't be removed, and if you and the people you work with are comfortable with it (and are prepared to hear the above over and over like just now), by all means, go for it.