# Creating Dummy Variables in v-for Loops

Tags: javascript, vue.js, user-interface, frontend, v-for

I am using Vue-JS and am running into an issue with `v-for` loops and `v-model` properties.

I have a list of items

```
<input
  v-for="i in list"
  v-model="i.model"
  ... (other tags that use i)
>
</input>
```

And some corresponding JavaScript

```
let model_thing = ref();

let list = [
  { model: ref(), data: "Whatever things" }
  { model: model_thing, data: "..." }, //I also tried something like this, where ref() is created outside of the list
]
```

But the issue is that the v-model simply doesn't work. I'm pretty sure this is due to the reference variable being in an array.

I think I have a way to solve this; it is a bit of a bad solution but a solution nonetheless.
I don't really need the v-model after the page has loaded (and for Vue to actually know what the input should have inside it).

So what if I could create a "dummy" variable inside the v-for loop?

```
<input
  v-for="i in list"
  v-model="let dummy = ref(); /* use 'dummy' as the ref"
  ... (whatever else)
>
</input>
```

The UI framework I'm using is also a bit undocumented (Known as [Maz-UI](https://louismazel.github.io/maz-ui-3/components/maz-select)), so I can't just pull a solution like this:

```
<!-- I am using select dropdowns instead of inputs like before -->
<MazSelect
  v-for="i in list"
  :value="i.model"
  @input="i.model = $event.target.value"
>
</MazSelect>
```

As this is just giving me `[object, Object]` and the placeholder text is still showing.

Can someone tell me how to create dummy variables like this?

Comment: I don't know about this specific case of ref unwrapping from within the template. The way you use v-model shouldn't be an issue, and creating temporaries is definitely a bad idea if at all possible. My guess is that it'll work if you put your array inside a call to `reactive` making it all reactive, quite possibly getting rid of the need for intermediate refs.

Comment: @Vivick Oh your `reactive([models])` suggestion did indeed work for my case. I did not know that even existed. Thank you very much. Although it may be a bit of bad practice, I would still like to know *if* one can actually implement the dummy variable solution; perhaps for another application.

Comment: @AndrewBaker There are only workarounds, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999618/how-to-define-a-temporary-variable-in-vue-js-template . If you need it, this means there's more idiomatic way to do this, potentially this is an indicator that you need to extract another component

Comment: I'll add a complete answer in a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there's nothing wrong with how you use `v-model`. So my guess is that it'd work when wrapped inside a `reactive`:

```
let model_thing = ref();

let list = reactive([
  { model: ref(), data: "Whatever things" }
  { model: model_thing, data: "..." }, //I also tried something like this, where ref() is created outside of the list
])
```

Note that due to [how `reactive` works](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#reactive), you can also get rid of intermediary `ref`s:

```
let list = reactive([
  { model: undefined, data: "Whatever things" }
  { model: undefined, data: "..." }, //I also tried something like this, where ref() is created outside of the list
])
```

Creating a temporary variable is usually a bad idea. Why? It's not reactive, meaning that only one part of the `v-model` would be useful: the binding part.

That said, the way you envisioned it is also impossible since Vue's JS compiler for binds only allows expressions (and not statements).

You can use literals, function calls, etc. but you can't create a proper variable, so to speak.

For these 2 reasons, I don't think you can create `ref`s on the fly. And as pointed out, when you reach such complex cases it's usually a sign that you need to refactor or subdivide.

Your issue does raise an interesting issue in data modelling: vertical (multiple arrays) vs horizontal grouping (one array of objects).